# Adding data to Hash Table using Powershell 'Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count"

Tags: powershell, active-directory, hashtable

I am teaching myself Powershell, and I am struggling to grasp Hash tables. I get the concept, but applying it is a whole other story.

I am using a 'Hey Scripting Guy' post as reference, http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/10/15/automatically-create-a-powershell-hash-table-10-15-11.aspx , namely this piece right here:

```
To create a hash table dynamically, follow these steps:
1.       Create an empty hash table.
2.       Store the empty hash table in a variable.
3.       Collect the data.
4.       Store the collected data in a variable.
5.       Use the foreach statement to walk through the collected data.
6.       Inside the loop call the add method to add the key value pairs to the hash table.

An example of this procedure is shown here:
$hash = $null
$hash = @{}
$proc = get-process | Sort-Object -Property name -Unique

foreach ($p in $proc)
{
 $hash.add($p.name,$p.id)
}
```

Which works great, however when I try to fit this to my needs, it breaks saying:

```
Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "1".
At line:15 char:10
+ $hash.add <<<< ($strGroup)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

Google turned up nothing relevant, so I turn to you, Stack Overflow Powershell users, what am I doing wrong here?

```
import-module activedirectory
$strDate = Get-Date
$strGroupList = get-content "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Documents\Group Audit\audit.txt"
$strGroupDetails = Get-ADGroupMember -identity $strGroup 


$strGroupList #list groups found

$hash= $null #empty the hash table
$hash = @{} 


foreach ($strGroup in $strGroupList)
{
$hash.add($strGroup)
}
```

What I am doing is simply reaching into a text file, grabbing the names of Active Directory groups, returning them (for purposes of stepping through the code), and the intention is to get all members of the groups in the each item in my list (text file), into separate arrays, by Group. For example:

```
Group1     Time/Date
------     ---------------
member1
member2
member3
member4

Group Owner:__________

Group2     Time/Date
------     ----------------
member1
member2
member3
member4

Group Owner:__________
```

The issue, is that I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I read through the post, did it his way just fine, but am having trouble with my way. I'm sure I fat fingered something, but I just can't find it!

Any help is appreciated, and any criticism is welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Every hash table entry consists of a key and a value.
Here:

```
$hash.add($p.name,$p.id)
```

you're adding a new entry to the hash table with a key of whatever is in $p.name, and a value of whatever is in $p.id.  There are two arguments to the .add method provided - one for the key and one for the value.

Here:

```
$hash.add($strGroup)
```

You are only providing one argument, and the method doesn't know what to do with that - it requires an argument for both the key and the value and there isn't enough there to work with.

Edit:

I think this might be closer to what you're trying to accomplish:

```
import-module activedirectory
$strDate = Get-Date
$strGroupList = get-content "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Documents\Group Audit\audit.txt"


$strGroupList #list groups found

$hash= $null #empty the hash table
$hash = @{} 


foreach ($strGroup in $strGroupList)
{
$strGroupDetails = Get-ADGroupMember -identity $strGroup 
$hash.add($strGroup,$strGroupDetails)
}
```

Comment: If you truly want to wait for a second pass to add values, you can set them initially to `$null` like: `$hash.add($strGroup,$null)`